# VB.NET Web Browser Youtube full screen not working

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I have been working on a simulation of windows 11, and it works, pretty well, but I added a web browser so you can browse the web and whenever i clicked on full screen mode on youtube, the video still shown, but the full screen part was all black.

[This is the video fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6MMw.png)

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have been searching the web for it and I can't find anything.